# Macro Links Keep Changing

Tags: excel, vba

We have a network drive "\deg-da-01\Data" that is being assigned to "Z:" drive. In my Excel Macro, I have an update instruction so the worksheet pulls data from a different worksheet in the network drive. Normally "Z:..." works, but occasionally it breaks and I have to change it to "\deg-da-01\Data...". After a few days, "\deg-da-01\Data..." fails to work and then I have to change it back to "Z:...". It seems that "\deg-da-01\Data..." and "Z:..." keeps switching back and forth. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Sounds like someone messed up the drive mapping, you could check to see if one path works and if not use the other. Or contact the sys admin to find out why they are not temporally consistent.

Comment: Can you use the UNC path for the file instead of relying on the drive mapping? The UNC path would presumably never change, whether or not the mapping is correct.

Comment: It is very strange. Generally, I keep my Excel Macros using the shortcut "Z:\..." which works for the most of the time. Then out of the blue, it will just break and I have to change it to the UNC path (restarting my computer doesn't help). However, that's not permanent. After a few days, the UNC path breaks and I have to change it back to "Z:\...". It is not clear if this is a issue with my network mapping or maybe Excel is not mapping it properly. Very strange and annoy.

Comment: Excel only sees the mapped drive - it's not involved in the actual mapping, so if you're having a problem with the mapping it's either your PC or your network that's the problem.

Comment: Did a bit more investigation and here is what I found. When I look at my directory, I see (1) Network drive \deg-da-01\Data (2) Z drive. They are equivalent - ie. I can go to my directory and files from either path. However, here is the difference, one shows \deg-da-01\Data... and another shows Z:\... So if I am opening the file using the network drive directory directly (ie. \deg-da-01\Data), all Macros must be in the \deg-da-01\Data format. And if I am opening the file from the Z:\ directory (even for the same file!), I have to use Z:\... in my Macro.

Comment: Until you figure it out, you can always use `On Error`. If you don't know how exactly, and if you can post the code, I'm sure someone could manage to do it.